# Different between DbContext.Find() and DbContext.SingleOrDefault() Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

What is the different when query data from context using `Find()` and `Single()`.
Both return the entity being requested.

Some example I found on Microsoft are using `Single`, `SingleOrDefault` variation to query for entity. Some uses `Find` method.

Are there any "performance" advantanges when using one over the other?

Comment: You left out the parameters, which would have (partly) answered your question: Find() only accepts the primary key, the Single() variations take a predicate. Usually that predicate will be matched to the PK and the performance should be equal then. But Single will always have a little more overhead and is easy to get wrong.

Comment: Actualöylö there are more differences. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696418(v=vs.113).aspx - find must not query the database if the answer can be taken from objects already loaded.

Comment: @bommelding Does this mean that the Find would only take the "ID" (primary key) as the argument? So actually Single has more dynamic and better use.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although they look the same they are very different in some fundamental ways

In short, `Find` starts by searching in the local cache of the context. If no match are found then it sends a query to the db.

**Documentation is your friend**

[DbSet.Find Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696418(v=vs.113).aspx)

> Finds an entity with the given primary key values. If an entity with
>   the given primary key values exists in the context, then it is
>   returned immediately without making a request to the store. Otherwise,
>   a request is made to the store for an entity with the given primary
>   key values and this entity, if found, is attached to the context and
>   returned. If no entity is found in the context or the store, then null
>   is returned.

[Queryable.SingleOrDefault Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.singleordefault?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Returns a single, specific element of a sequence, or a default value
>   if no such element is found.

[Queryable.FirstOrDefault Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.firstordefault?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Returns the first element of a sequence, or a default value if no
>   element is found.

**More-so**

[Querying and Finding Entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/)

> The Find method on DbSet uses the primary key value to attempt to find
>   an entity tracked by the context. If the entity is not found in the
>   context then a query will be sent to the database to find the entity
>   there. Null is returned if the entity is not found in the context or
>   in the database.
>
> Find is different from using a query in two significant ways:
>
> - A round-trip to the database will only be made if the entity with the given key is not found in the context.
> - Find will return entities that are in the Added state. That is, Find will return entities that have been added to the context but have not
>     yet been saved to the database.

**Update**

> Does this mean that if the entitiy was already being tracked (through
>   lazy loading), then Find would actually have a better performance
>   advantange when trying to querying again?

Yes it will have better performance

Comment: Does this mean that if the entitiy was already being tracked (through lazy loading), then Find would actually have a better performance advantange when trying to querying again?